# Dúvida react-native

Tags: react-native

Gostaria de saber se um aplicativo que atualize, por exemplo, uma pequena lista de informações automaticamente, ao sofrerem alterações no banco de dados (essas alterações não feitas no app vem outro lugar ) sem precisar pressionar qualquer botão, é simples de fazer e se tem algum problema de performance ou boa prática.

Comment: Ate onde eu sei atualizações em tempo real dependem de um "HOSPEDEIRO  PARA CONSTRUIR APLICATIVOS EM TEMPO REAL" que eu creio que seja isso que você procura, existe um chamado "Pusher" la você pode fazer uma integração com sua API e lá tem várias linguagens provavelmente tem alguma forma de integrar com o react-native e fazer sua lista atualizar em tempo real, sem precisar clicar no botão.

Comment: *"é simples de fazer"* Isso depende do seu nível de habilidade ;)

Comment: No caso eu tenho fire base, estou procurando alguns exemplos para usar como base. Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você utilize da tecnologia para fins de **exibição** (FrontEnd), é possível sim. Não que não seja possível executar eventos, programar tratamento de dados e etc. Mas pela "Facilidade", dá sim.

Com React-Native você pode criar a interface, já que, a tecnologia [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) é um framework para UI, "...*building user interfaces*...".

Isso você pode programar um evento ou uma função no ciclo de vida dos componentes(Conceito chave do React) para sempre que você abrir aquela "Lista", ele fazer uma requisição para um Servidor Web(WebService) e exibir essa lista.

Não precisaria de Botão. Bastava abrir o aplicativo e ele atualizaria o conteúdo toda vez que abrisse aquela tela.

Fazendo uso da função [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), juntamente com as chamadas do [ComponentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) dá para conseguir atingir seu objetivo sem muita dificuldade.

O nível de dificuldade varia de acordo com seus conhecimentos sobre Javascript e a tecnologia React.

Espero ter ajudado, bom desenvolvimento!

Comment: Caso queira em tempo real a atualização, existem tecnologias que podem fazer a atualização automática. Não é difícil, é complexo. Coisas diferentes. Minha sugestão é: Coisas simples, soluções simples. Já que o servidor atualiza os dados, delegar a responsabilidade para consultar alterações do servidor ao dispositivo e não ao servidor. Deixe o dispositivo requerer uma tag, versão, quantidade de registros, numero de last patch, caso dê mismatch, puxe novamente os dados. Simples assim.